# Help to create this image with Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I'd like to re-create this image using `circuitikz`. However, I have never used it before and I am struggling to wrap my head around it (I have watched youtube videos and flicked through the manual).

[image]

I have tried things that seem to make sense to me but they just seem to mess the circuit up.

Could someone please help me here?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[american] \draw
     (0,0) to[R=$r_d$,o-] (0,3)    
           to[R=$R_S$,-o] (0,6)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[european, americancurrents]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ylen}{2cm}
\newcommand{\dx}{\ylen}
\newcommand{\dy}{.5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} 
    \coordinate (A);
    \node at (A) [right] {A};
    \draw (A) to[short, o-] ++(0,-\dy)
        coordinate (j-1)
        to[R=$R_\text{S}$, *-*] ++(0,-\ylen)
        coordinate (j-2)
        to[short] ++(0,-\dy)
        coordinate (j-3)
        to[R=$r_\text{d}$, *-*] ++(0,-\ylen)
        coordinate (j-4)
        to[short, -o] ++(0,-\dy)
        node [right] {K};

    \draw (j-1) -- ++(\dx, 0) to[current source] ++(0, -\ylen) -- (j-2);
    \draw (j-3) -- ++(\dx, 0) to[current source] ++(0, -\ylen) -- (j-4);
    \draw (j-3) -- ++(-\dx, 0) to[C] ++(0, -\ylen) -- (j-4);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

I recommend to take a look at the [tikz documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) to see how coordinates can be specified (pages 37--38). It also explains the `++` syntax which I have used.